# Difference between "bin/zkServer.sh start" and "bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am newbie in apache kafka and to understand kafka terminology I refer tutorialpoints.
In [link1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_installation_steps.htm) it use "bin/zkServer.sh start" command to start zookeeper server and In [link2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_basic_operations.htm) it use "bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties".

Is there any difference between this two commands or both are same?

Comment: Why not use the official getting started guide on the Apache pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both commands do the same, they start ZooKeeper.

The command [`zkServer.sh`](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/bin/zkServer.sh) is from the ZooKeeper project.

The command [`zookeeper-server-start.sh`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh) is from the Kafka project. As it relies on ZooKeeper, it's useful to have a command to start it directly without needing the full ZooKeeper project.

The one you use typically depends how/why you use ZooKeeper. If it's while working on Kafka, you can use `zookeeper-server-start.sh`. If you only have ZooKeeper then used the other one.

Answer (score 0):

As Mickael Maison replied, they both start the same process but from different projects, the one from Kafka and the second from zookeeper.
Although, be carefull when when you start zookeeper-server-start.sh and then start a broker in the same server with : kafka-server-start.sh.
It will use the same log directory, and DailyRollingFileAppender cannot will give you error on each date change. No backup action will be done

For instance: log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [c:/Kafka/logs/server.log] to [c:/Kafka/logs/server.log.2024-01-23-10].

So the best practice should be to run from separated servers these two services zookeeper and kafka or to use zookeeper from other project in the same server.